# Making a circular barplot with a hollow center (aka race track plot)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I was asked to recreate the following style of plot.  (Please ignore the question of whether this is a good type of visualization and charitably consider this as adding a colorful element to a numeric table.)

Most of it is pretty straightforward, but I have not yet found a good way to make the center hollow.  In the interest of time, I may resort to the kludge of adding invisible dummy data (I'll post that approach if no one else does, but it seems less optimal than one that modifies the theme).  Is there a theme-based solution or a non-ggplot2 R solution?

### What we're imitating

[image]

### Simple ggplot2 result (undesired filled center)

```
library(ggplot2)

# make sample dataframe

Category <- c("Electronics", "Appliances", "Books", "Music", "Clothing", 
            "Cars", "Food/Beverages", "Personal Hygiene", 
            "Personal Health/OTC", "Hair Care")
Percent <- c(81, 77, 70, 69, 69, 68, 62, 62, 61, 60)

internetImportance<-data.frame(Category,Percent)

# append number to category name
internetImportance$Category <-
     paste0(internetImportance$Category," - ",internetImportance$Percent,"%")

# set factor so it will plot in descending order 
internetImportance$Category <-
    factor(internetImportance$Category, 
    levels=rev(internetImportance$Category))

# plot

ggplot(internetImportance, aes(x = Category, y = Percent,
    fill = Category)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 0.9, stat="identity") + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    ylim(c(0,100)) +
    ggtitle("Top Product Categories Influenced by Internet") +
    geom_text(data = internetImportance, hjust = 1, size = 3,
              aes(x = Category, y = 0, label = Category)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

How can we plot these data with a hollow center?

Comment: In case it helps, this sort of plot is sometimes called a race track plot.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks! I'll add that term in above to help searchers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a non-ggplot2 (base R graphics) solution using the `plotrix` package, which contains two nice functions: `draw.circle()` and `draw.arc()`:

```
circBarPlot <- function(x, labels, colors=rainbow(length(x)), cex.lab=1) {
  require(plotrix)
  plot(0,xlim=c(-1.1,1.1),ylim=c(-1.1,1.1),type="n",axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
  radii <- seq(1, 0.3, length.out=length(x))
  draw.circle(0,0,radii,border="lightgrey")
  angles <- (1/4 - x)*2*pi
  draw.arc(0, 0, radii, angles, pi/2, col=colors, lwd=130/length(x), lend=2, n=100)
  ymult <- (par("usr")[4]-par("usr")[3])/(par("usr")[2]-par("usr")[1])*par("pin")[1]/par("pin")[2]
  text(x=-0.02, y=radii*ymult, labels=paste(labels," - ", x*100, "%", sep=""), pos=2, cex=cex.lab)
}

circBarPlot(Percent/100, Category)
text(0,0,"GLOBAL",cex=1.5,col="grey")
```

It gives me:

[image: Circular bar plot]

Comment: +1 This is great.  I haven't used plotrix before; those two functions will be super useful in the future.

Answer (score 24):

I think an immediate fix is to create some "empty" entries. I'd create `internetImportance` data.frame like this:

```
Category <- c("Electronics", "Appliances", "Books", "Music", "Clothing", 
        "Cars", "Food/Beverages", "Personal Hygiene", 
        "Personal Health/OTC", "Hair Care")
Percent <- c(81, 77, 70, 69, 69, 68, 62, 62, 61, 60)

internetImportance <- data.frame(Category,Percent)

len <- 4
df2 <- data.frame(Category = letters[1:len], Percent = rep(0, len), 
                                 Category2 = rep("", len))
internetImportance$Category2 <- 
 paste0(internetImportance$Category," - ",internetImportance$Percent,"%")

# append number to category name
internetImportance <- rbind(internetImportance, df2)

# set factor so it will plot in descending order 
internetImportance$Category <-
    factor(internetImportance$Category, 
    levels=rev(internetImportance$Category))
```

And then I'd plot `ggplot2` with `fill=category2` as follows:

```
ggplot(internetImportance, aes(x = Category, y = Percent,
    fill = Category2)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 0.9, stat="identity") + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    ylim(c(0,100)) +
    ggtitle("Top Product Categories Influenced by Internet") +
    geom_text(data = internetImportance, hjust = 1, size = 3,
              aes(x = Category, y = 0, label = Category2)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

This gives me:

[image]

You can add a `geom_text(label="GLOBAL", x=.5, y=.5, size=4) +` before `theme_minimal` to add the text `GLOBAL`.

Comment: +1 This is almost exactly the solution I ended up using.  I am still kinda hoping for a theme-based solution manipulating some obscure parameter controlling whitespace in barplots.  But as time goes on, that seems less probable.

Answer (score 13):

Another `base` solution that doesn't rely on `plotrix` package:

```
circular.barplot<-function(values, labels, col, cex){
    df<-data.frame(values=sort(values), labels=labels[order(values)])
    col<-col[order(values)]
    plot(NA,xlim=c(-1.3,1.3),ylim=c(-1.3,1.3),axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, asp=1)
    t<-sapply(df$values,function(x).5*pi-seq(0, 2*pi*x/100,length=1000))
    x<-sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x)(.3+x/nrow(df))*cos(t[,x]))
    y<-sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x)(.3+x/nrow(df))*sin(t[,x]))
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
        lines(x=x[,i],y=y[,i],col=col[i],lwd=10,lend=1)
        text(x[1,i],y[1,i],paste(df$labels[i]," - ",df$values[i],"%",sep=""),
             pos=2,cex=cex)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since the plot is circular, it can be easily done by `circlize` package.

First the data:

```
Category <- c("Electronics", "Appliances", "Books", "Music", "Clothing", 
        "Cars", "Food/Beverages", "Personal Hygiene", 
        "Personal Health/OTC", "Hair Care")
Percent <- c(81, 77, 70, 69, 69, 68, 62, 62, 61, 60)
color = rainbow(length(Percent))
```

Reverse the three vectors since `circlize` adds each element from inside to outside by default:

```
Category = rev(Category)
Percent = rev(Percent)
color = rev(color)
```

If you image the circle is a bent plot region, then it is just adding rectangles, lines and texts.

```
library(circlize)

par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
circos.par("start.degree" = 90)
circos.initialize("a", xlim = c(0, 100)) # 'a` just means there is one sector
circos.trackPlotRegion(ylim = c(0.5, length(Percent)+0.5), track.height = 0.8, 
    bg.border = NA, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
    xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim") # in fact, it is c(0, 100)
    for(i in seq_along(Percent)) {
        circos.lines(xlim, c(i, i), col = "#CCCCCC")
        circos.rect(0, i - 0.45, Percent[i], i + 0.45, col = color[i], 
            border = "white")
        circos.text(xlim[2], i, paste0(Category[i], " - ", Percent[i], "%"), 
            adj = c(1, 0.5)) 
    }
})
circos.clear()

text(0, 0, "GLOBAL", col = "#CCCCCC")
```

[image]